# ¿Qué hacer para que mi aplicación Android sea compatible con un Moto G y resoluciones similares?

Tags: android

Hice una aplicación para resoluciones 2560x1440,la estuve testeando en un Moto G con Android 5.01, al momento de subirla a la play, intenté buscarla desde el mismo dispositivo y tal parece que no es compatible porque no la encuentro.

Esto coloqué en el archivo Manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"

    android:normalScreens="true"

    android:largeScreens="true"
/>
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal"/>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
    android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
    android:screenSize="xlarge" />
```

**EDICIÓN**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0.1a">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"

        android:normalScreens="true"

        android:largeScreens="true"
    />
    <compatible-screens>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal"/>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
       <!-- android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"  -->



    <!--     android:resizeable="true"/>-->
    <!-- android:anyDensity="true"-->
    <!--<compatible-screens>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    </compatible-screens>
    -->

    <application
        android:name="xx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/xxxxxxxxxx"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="mx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xx.xx.xxxxxxxxxx.GameScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game_screen"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xx.xxxxx.mxxxxxxxxe.VideoView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video_view"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xx.xx.xxxxxx.xxxx"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cards_view"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xx.xx.xxxxxxxxx.AboutScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about_screen"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xx.xxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.VideoPlay"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video_play"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Hay que aclara que la tengo en todos los países, requiere mínimo Android Ice Cream.

¿Podría alguien orientarme a que se debe que no lo reconozca como dispositivo compatible?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: @xAmp73r Agrega los uses-features indicados en mi respuesta, podría ver que aplicación es desde playstore?

Comment: Es esta https://goo.gl/WhlZsM

Comment: En tu caso si la aplicación esta definida para uso en resoluciones 2560x1440, Al tratar de instalarla en tu dispositivo Moto G que tiene una resolución 720 x 1280 pixels (~326 ppi pixel density), no será compatible.

Comment: Ah ok, muchas garcias por tu tiempo, intentaré agregar esa resolución y comento el resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo eh resuelto solo removiendo `<compatible-screens>`:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal"/>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
    android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
    android:screenSize="xlarge" />
```

La respuesta es algo obvia ya que se está delimitando a ciertos dispositivos con ciertas características de pantalla.

**EDICIÓN**

No veo la necesidad de poner todo el contenido del Manifest, debido a que es demasiada información que no es de utilidad para este caso:

De esta manera tengo para el soporte de versiones, omití el atributo *`android:targetSdkVersion`*

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>
```

En **build.gradle** está así:

```
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode xx
    versionName "x.x.xx"

}
```

Comment: Hola has probado quitando todo este bloque? si deseas fuera compatible tu aplicación con la mayoría de los dispositivos, yo no lo agregaría, ve mi respuesta! :).

Comment: el target SDK a que númeración lo tienes? Lo digo que yo he hecho el eror de poner a 23 y de golpe mi app ha dejado de ser compatible con mis 3 dispositivos, y no se pude volver atrás una vez subido a googleplay

Comment: @Elenasys Así es, creo que no viste mi bien mi respuesta, "Lo eh resuelto solo removiendo <compatible-screens>:", es decir, anteriormente lo tenìa, se lo eh quitado y se resolvió, lo resolví antes que editaras tu respuesta, muchas gracias por tomarte tiempo :D

Comment: @Webserveis el target lo tengo que sea compatible desde Ice Cream(15) hasta 23(Marshmallow), no tengo ningún problema con eso, lo reconoce en un Kit Kat y en Lollipop sin problema.

Comment: @x4mp73r no me refería al minSDk mas bien, si estableces algún valor en android:targetSdkVersion o bien omites ese atributo, seria de agradecer que editaras la respuesta con el manifest.xml entero

Comment: @Webserveis Ya edité mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Regularmente el filtrado desde la `playstore` para ciertos dispositivos se debe también a que no cuentan con ciertas características de hardware que usa tu aplicación.

puedes agregar:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />
```

Es importante también revisar:

- Que idiomas son compatibles para tu aplicación.
- En que paises es soportada tu aplicación.
- mínimo Sistema operativo soportado.

En tu caso si la aplicación esta definida para uso en resoluciones 2560x1440, Al tratar de instalarla en tu dispositivo Moto G que tiene una resolución 720 x 1280 pixels (~326 ppi pixel density), no será compatible.

**A mi parecer este bloque no sería necesario:**

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"

    android:normalScreens="true"

    android:largeScreens="true"
/>
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal"/>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
    android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
    android:screenSize="xlarge" />
```

**si quisieras fuera compatible con la 
mayoría de los dispositivos.**

Comment: ¿En caso de que mi app no contenga nada de eso?, es decir, no hago uso nada de la lista.

Comment: a mi me sucedió que pensaba no tener problema y al final teníamos una método para marcado telefónico en tablets. Permiteme revisar tu aplicación desde la playstore y te doy mas detalles.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me pasa lo mismo, que las aplicaciones realizadas con Android Studio me indica que no tengo dispositivos compatibles

He descompilado el `manifest.xml` de una aplicación realizada con Phonegap y que me muestra correctamente todos los dispositivos, en la sección de especificar compatibilidad de tamaño de pantalla de los dispositivos:

```
<supports-screens 
        android:anyDensity="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:xlargeScreens="true">   
    </supports-screens>
```

y las versiones del SDK

```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

Elimina maxSdkVersion, automáticamente siempre será visible para los nuevas actualizaciones de Android.

Comment: Ok, gracias por tu respuesta, deja hago lo que dices y comento que tal me va.